# My Superfish menu is being repeated 4 times. Why?

Tags: navigation

My superfish menu is being displayed 4 times. In the header. I originally selected 4 from the dropdown menu, but have since changed it to 1. Even after clearing the cache, the menu is being repeated 4 times. How do I fix this?

Comment: if you found the solution could you please write it as a separate answer..you will help the community to identify quickly the solution..thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed. I did all sorts of things but it looks like it was just being cached.